# Can Firefox have 2 Windows or Tabs open side by side, each for a different profile (one for work, one for personal use)? IE 8 can but can't remember the profiles

Tags: firefox, session, firefox-profile

It seems that Firefox can use ProfileManager by

```
firefox.exe -ProfileManager
```

but then it seems like if a profile "work" and another profile "personal" are created, you can't have them side by side running at the same time?  (either in 2 windows or 2 tabs).

```
firefox.exe -p work
firefox.exe -p personal
```

the second time, the firefox is using the "work" profile again.

Any way to make it work?  IE 8 can have a "File -> New Session" but you have to log in every time.  You can't make them as profiles and remember the sessions it had with gmail, etc.  (need to do a login again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a How-To-Geek Tutorial:

**[Use Multiple Firefox Profiles at the Same Time](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/use-multiple-firefox-profiles-at-the-same-time/)**

Comment: it seems to work!  the only key here seems to be the -no-remote, as in firefox.exe -p work -no-remote

Comment: Yse, -no-remote is the key.