# Can you run more than one Firefox profile instance at the same time?

Tags: firefox, security, firefox-profile

I was thinking it would be a good idea to run administrative functions in a browser that isn't in the same firefox profile as the one I use for regular browsing.  Is it possible to run more than one firefox profile at the same time on Windows?  When I run `firefox -P` while firefox is running I just end up with a new window.  Is firefox a singleton on windows?

Comment: "Is firefox a singleton on windows?" - **It is not.**  [Can Firefox have 2 Windows or Tabs open side by side, each for a different profile (one for work, one for personal use)? IE 8 can but can't remember the profiles](http://superuser.com/questions/69795/can-firefox-have-2-windows-or-tabs-open-side-by-side-each-for-a-different-profi?rq=1).

Comment: [Running Multiple Instances of Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/124429/running-multiple-instances-of-firefox?rq=1)

Comment: [Running more than one Firefox Profile at once?](http://superuser.com/questions/440189/running-more-than-one-firefox-profile-at-once?rq=1)

Comment: [Bug 716110 - split -new-instance flag out of existing -no-remote flag](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716110)

Comment: It is a good idea - I use separate browsers (Chrome for regular use and development, Firefox with no extensions other than LastPass) for handling sensitive admin duties.  I find that's much easier than trying to disentangle two profiles from one browser.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov It doesn't hurt to have different themes too, so you can tell them apart.